# Understanding how @Taquito/Beacon works

Tags: taquito, wallets, api, beacon

I've entered the wonderful world of Tezos from an EVM based background, with some familiarity with Web3/EthersJS. I'm currently trying to understand how dApps communicate with wallets. From my understanding, TZIP-10 is the proposal which sets the standards for how dApps can communicate to Wallets. I understand that Beacon is the implementation of this standard, but I have some confusion between a few repositories and would really appreciate if anyone could help clarify my understanding.

I'm trying to understand what the difference between @taquito/beacon and @airgap/beacon-sdk is:
What roles do they play?
Is the Beacon-SDK developed by AirGap required to use a wallet?
What is the equivalent of a provider injection on Tezos?

Answer (score 2):

Taquito is a library for building dApps and wallets from ECAD. Beacon is a library to communicate from a dApp to a wallet from AirGap

If you look at the source code for @taquito/beacon-wallet here: https://github.com/ecadlabs/taquito/blob/master/packages/taquito-beacon-wallet/src/taquito-beacon-wallet.ts you will see that it imports the airgap SDK

@Taquito/Beacon is simply a wrapper around airgap beacon to allow taquito users to easily add it to their dApps / wallets

Comment: Thanks! That was super helpful, is AirGap Beacon the only library that supports being able to communicate from dApp to Wallets or are there also alternative solutions?

Comment: @HevarAbrihem Beacon is the only one in production. Possible there will be others in the future. Currently everything in Tezos uses Beacon

Comment: Gotcha, so I'd have to re-build Beacon from  the ground up essentially if I want to connect a custom wallet / customise the modal

Comment: @Hevar no not at all. The modal has a predefined list of known wallets to choose from (that you could be added too once the wallet is available), the other option opens a QR code that any other wallet can use to connect to the dApp. Thats how wallets test while in development

Answer (score 0):

To your question in the comment, I think it will be (probably soon) possible to use Walletconnect v2 via Taquito for communication.
See the following github links in Taquito and Beacon:

- [Implement a wallet provider for wallet connect 2](https://github.com/ecadlabs/taquito/issues/2145)
- [Support wallet connect 2 in the Taquito test dapp](https://github.com/ecadlabs/taquito/issues/2146)
- [Explore WalletConnect 2.0](https://github.com/ecadlabs/taquito/issues/2052)
- [Beacon -> WalletConnect functionality](https://github.com/airgap-it/beacon-sdk/issues/351)

Comment: Hey David, I've heard that there are a few people working on this, I'm wondering if anyone has tried to build a simple wallet connector that has a customisable modal, or if is there is any library to start building a simple Beacon-like implementation for wallets.